# Scheme Function to sum even numbers

Tags: math, scheme, lisp, addition

I need to create a recursive function in scheme to sum up the first n numbers of even numbers.

```
(define (even-sum n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= (modulo n 2) 0) (+ n (even-sum (- n 2))))))
```

This is what I have so far but it only runs n number of times instead of summing the first n number of even numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot to handle the case when `n` is odd:

```
(define (even-sum n)
  (cond ((<= n 0) 0)
        ((= (modulo n 2) 0)
         (+ n (even-sum (- n 2))))
        (else (even-sum (- n 1)))))
```

By the way: you can achieve the same result with a simple formula, assuming that `n >= 0`. There is no need to iterate!

```
(define (even-sum n)
  (let ((m (if (even? n) n (- n 1))))
    (* (+ m 2) (/ m 4))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(even-sum 1001)
=> 250500
```